# Referencing Themes in a dll in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, app.xaml

I am using an opensource wpf TreeListView control. The control is a library project with a themes folder in it containing some xaml theme files. In my wpf project, I have got a reference to the control dll and I would like to know how to reference the dll themes in app.xaml. I tried doing something like this but it throws exception saying can't find the treelistview assembly

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>           
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/TreeListView;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

At the moment I have to copy all the theme files in my wpf project locally to make it work like this.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>               
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
         <ResourceDictionary Source="themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Is there a way to reference theme files directly in the TreeListView dll like referencing default themes.

Awaiting
Nabeel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out myself, I was using the wrong assembly file name.

Comment: can you then please accept your ownl answer or delete your question? thanks in advance